# Big Oh time complexity for alpha(n)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

What does O(alpha(n)) mean? I recently stumbled upon 2048 but in terms of run times and one of the blocks had that. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see that version of 2048?

Comment: http://sarthakm.me/Big-Oh/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to be a reference to the [inverse Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse), written as `α(n)`

From wikipedia:

> This inverse appears in the time complexity of some algorithms, such as the disjoint-set data structure and Chazelle's algorithm for minimum spanning trees.

Comment: Is there is a Big-O complexity of Beta or Theta ?